Getting AADSTS65001 error (invalid_grant) when trying to refresh access_token for ordinary outlook.com email with valid refresh_token
I'm trying to use the OAuth2 flow to authenticate for IMAP/SMTP usage for various email services (mainly Gmail and Outlook)[1].  Learning from various existing examples, it basically requires providing an authentication URL to obtain an initial access_token and refresh_token, and a token URL to refresh access_token using the refresh_token obtained previously.  This works pretty smoothly for Gmail (with a few extra parameters when doing authentication); For Outlook, I am able to get an access_token and refresh_token, however refreshing to token results in the following error:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": ""AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '3bcc403f-3d50-4a8e-b457-8519fc37656f' named 'oauth2-email'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: 58754f6d-fd30-4bd0-9be2-943a77476200 Correlation ID: 0f2a7b6e-ac32-484b-bf40-091be6621822 Timestamp: 2024-07-24 09:07:26Z",
  "error_codes": 65001,
  "timestamp": "2024-07-24 09:07:26Z",
  "trace_id": "58754f6d-fd30-4bd0-9be2-943a77476200",
  "correlation_id": "0f2a7b6e-ac32-484b-bf40-091be6621822",
  "suberror": "consent_required"
}

More specifically, I am accessing the following URL for the authorization request:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{redacted_tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={redacted_client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
&scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2FIMAP.AccessAsUser.All%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2FSMTP.Send
&access_type=offline
&prompt=consent

This will prompt me to login using my account and accept access to the permission of the items listed in "scope".  After which, the browser will redirect to the redirect_uri with code in the URL (which was pretty obscure compared with Gmail which even gives a button to copy the code into clipboard).  With this code, I make another request to the token URL as follow:
POST /{redact_tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
HOST https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={redacted_client_id}
&client_secret={redacted_client_secret}
&code={the_one_I_received_in_previous_step}
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
&grant_type=authorization_code

And then I successfully get access_token and refresh_token.  (Note that the last 2 args are required for Gmail.  Adding or removing them doesn't seem to make a difference for Outlook as I can get the access_token and refresh_token either way.  Do correct me if I'm wrong.)
However, when I try to refresh the access_token with the following request:
POST /{redact_tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
HOST https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={redacted_client_id}
&client_secret={redacted_client_secret}
&refresh_token={refresh_token_received_in_previous_step}
&grant_type=refresh_token

I get the error I posted in the beginning.
I have followed various related answers on stackoverflow, such as

adding API permissions listed in scope at App registration -> {app_name} -> API permissions and ensure I clicked Grant admin consent for Default Directory (both Delegation and Application),
set Allow user consent for apps in User consent settings,
set Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to​  to yes in Admin consent settings,
in Authentication -> Redirection URIs, ensure both Access tokens (used for implicit flows) and ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows) are checked,

And it's still giving me the same error.  What confuses me the most is that I can get access_token and refresh_token in grant_type=authorization_code, but not in grant_type=refresh_token, where both requests are done through the same endpoint.
I have also tried the following:

Using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token gives me an unauthorized error, which seems to be only usable for organization or office365 users.
Removing prompt=consent in authorization request, which won't prompt me for login but only let me consent to the API permissions, which can grant me refresh_token but still gives me the same error on refreshing.
Changing redirect_uri doesn't make any difference.
Changing scope to offline_access http://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read http://outlook.office.com/Mail.Send as suggested in some examples, same error.
Expose an API, adding client application using my client_id, and grant admin consent to that API.
Using https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id} to request consent to client_id.

None of the above worked.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
[1] Mainly for use in Emacs with Gnus/smtpmail, though the issue is general and applies to other clients as well.

Turns out that refreshing access_token was disabled from outlook.com and clients are supposed to migrate to use the Outlook app or compatible apps (confirmed by MS representative through online chat).  I have put in a request to re-enable this and let's see how it goes: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/069f1816-0a55-ef11-b4ad-0022484d3ecc
